# Hide div when value is greater than 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a div to show when days remaining is less than 0

i have this working on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agw5aero/1/)
but when i try open this anywhere else it wont run

```js
if ($('.daysrem').html() >= 0) {
  $("#warningexp").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="daysrem">3</div>
<br>
<div id="warningexp"><span style="background-color: red; padding: 10px; color:white; font-size:16px"><b>MEMBERSHIP EXPIRED</b></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your div match as lonic said and like it does on your jsfiddle, you may have forget the document.ready()

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if ($('.daysrem').html() >= 1) {
     $("#warningexp").hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's easy. Your code point to a classname `.daysrem`. Your HTML instead has a class `.days_remaining`. They just don't match. Additionally your code points to hide a div with the id `#warningexp`, in your HTML instead you have a div with `#expired`. You need to take care of those classes and id's. If your jQuery code don't match with them, it just can't work.

Try this instead:

```js
if ($('.days_remaining').html() >= 0) {
  $("#expired").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="days_remaining">3</div>
<br>
<div id="expired"><span style="background-color: red; padding: 10px; color:white; font-size:16px"><b>MEMBERSHIP EXPIRED</b></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
if ($('.daysrem').text() >= 0) {
  $("#warningexp").hide();
}
```

Hope this helps.